# Error in using mt19937 with random_device as static class members

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have a class called *RandomNumberGenerator* using which I want to generate a random number using **mt19937 algorithm**.

I am creating an object of *random_device* to work as seed.

When I compile, I am getting an error that says:
`"No member named generate in std::__1::random_device".`
I am not able to understand the error. Perhaps I am doing something wrong in the way I am initializing the objects of *random_device* and **mt19937** but I am unable to figure out what's wrong.
Appreciate some help..

**RandomNumberGenerator.h**

```
class RandomNumberGenerator
{
    static std::random_device   m_rd;
    static std::mt19937         m_rng;
public:
    static double getRandomNumber(const double& rangeStart, const double& rangeEnd);
};
```

**RandomNumberGenerator.cpp**

```
#include "RandomNumberGenerator.h"

std::random_device   RandomNumberGenerator::m_rd;
std::mt19937         RandomNumberGenerator::m_rng(RandomNumberGenerator::m_rd);

double RandomNumberGenerator::getRandomNumber(const double& rangeStart, const double& rangeEnd)
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> randomizer(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
    return randomizer(m_rng);
}
```

Comment: Is there any other information I can provide?

Comment: @Hardik maybe you should take it in consideration: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Ah, you missed only one small item.

```
std::mt19937 RandomNumberGenerator::m_rng(RandomNumberGenerator::m_rd);
```

The above line is sending the instance and not the seed.  Therefore it must have a `generate` function to provide the seed, which it does not have.  Simply change that line to call the functor, and all is well.

```
std::mt19937 RandomNumberGenerator::m_rng(RandomNumberGenerator::m_rd());
```

**NOTE:**

One other item to note is that you are allocating a new `std::uniform_real_distribution` on each call.  While distribution objects are light weight, consider making that static as well, as long as the `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd` remain the same for subsequent calls.  However if you make that decision, initializing the range values will be a tougher call.

If your program doesn't use this class during the whole lifetime, consider making this an instance class, and take the range on the ctor,  allowing complete cleanup following the generation of numbers.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

If you definitely want this to be static, another option would be to allocate and completely cleanup all objects in a function that will fill all needed values, similar to the following:

```
template<typename T, typename DISTRIBUTION_T>
static void fill(T* buffer, uint32_t const count, T const min, T const max)
{
    ASSERT(buffer);
    ASSERT(count);
    ASSERT(max > min);

    std::random_device randomDevice { };
    std::mt19937_64 twisterEngine { randomDevice() };
    DISTRIBUTION_T distribution(min, max);
    for (uint32_t i = 0u; i < count; ++i)
        buffer[i] = distribution(twisterEngine);
}
```

Then use this for various types like the following:

```
uint32_t const COUNT = 31u;
double realValues[COUNT];
uint32_t intValues[COUNT];

RandomNumberGenerator::fill<double, std::uniform_real_distribution<double>>(realValues, COUNT, 100.0, 200.0);
RandomNumberGenerator::fill<uint32_t, std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t>>(intValues, COUNT, 100u, 200u);
```

If that looks like an ugly interface then make `fill` private, and provide clean public methods to provide a few types you wish to support.

Comment: In the `fill` function, shouldn't at least the `random_device` be static?

Comment: Why would you want to keep it around?  After the fill has completed, you likely would want it cleaned up, unless you are calling `fill` a tremendous number of times.